# Incorrect width flex items with gap and fixed flex-basis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When using `flex: 1` on flex items flexbox will take care of properly sizing your items, no matter if you add margins (a gap) or not. All items will remain the same width. However consider a case where a flex item is the same width as in the flexbox where all items are using `flex: 1` but without the item being nested in that flexbox. Instead it's nested in a different flexbox with less children so using just `flex: 1` is not an option. You have to specify a `max-width` or `flex-basis` to equalize the width to one of the items in the flexbox with only items using `flex: 1`.

The closest I manage to get is by using `flex: 0 1 <width>%` or `max-width: <width>%` (same result).

I think the problem is the margins because without it, it's not an issue. But I know the margin size also I do know how many margins will be used when duplicating the width of an other flexbox's items.

Have a look at this example:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

ul li.fourth {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}

/* The irrelavent part start here */
ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
ul li {
  height: 100px;
}
ul:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(even),
ul:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
ul:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(odd),
ul:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="fourth"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so in other words, you want all the item from the first and second list to be equal ? by specifying flex:1 to the first one ?

Comment: Please include the example with code in the post. You'll get more eyes and responses, and it makes it easier for people to reference the code as they read your question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, but as well to the second one. Excluding to the item what has to be the same width as the items in the first list.

Comment: @adpro added code from the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, found a way to do it!

By using `max-width` with `calc()` and the following formula:

```
(100% * 1/$items) - (($gap * ($items - 1)) / $items)
```

In the example below variable `$gap` is `25px` and for class `.fourth` the `$items` variable in the formula above is `4` for class `.fifth` the variable `$items` is `5`.

Resulting in the following css:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
ul li {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
ul li.fourth {
  max-width: calc(25% - 18.75px);
}
ul li.fifth {
  max-width: calc(20% - 20px);
}

/* The irrelavent part start here */
ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
ul li {
  height: 100px;
}
ul:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(even),
ul:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
ul:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(odd),
ul:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="fourth"></li>
</ul>
<p><hr></p>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="fifth"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That work for `flex-basis` too. And `(100% - ((items - 1) * gap)) / items` is a simpler formula (`flex: 0 calc((100% - 75px) / 4);`). Do note, using `calc` for _flex-basis_ value with shorthand `flex` doesn't work on IE.